# I am getting issue in changing inner HTML of div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, ng-bind-html, angularjs-compile

I found a problem in changing html of div:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lab")[0].setAttribute("ng-bind-html", "binds"); 
$scope.binds="<h1>run</h1>";
```

I am setting attribute `ng-bind-html`in java script because I have have integrated some plugin in my code in which `div` of `class="lab"` is getting declared through JavaScript. The attribute `binds` is attached properly, I checked this in inspect element. In fact whenever I attached property of `ng-bind-html` in JavaScript then `ng-bind-html` does not work. What is the correct way to do it? There is no error in the code.

Comment: I'm no expert for angular js, but I do know that it needs to parse the html attributes in order to setup the event handling. If you have JS running around adding attributes after this parsing has occurred angularjs might not know about it.

If this is the case, you might try to fix it by programmatically (with js) binding the element instead of setting an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have added `ng-bind-html` attribute dynamically, which will add directive attribute to the DOM but `ng-bind-html` directive wouldn't get evaluated the html content. You need to recompile that DOM using

```
$compile(document.getElementsByClassName("lab")[0])($scope)
```

To making sure this should work you need to add `ngSanitize` module in your angular app.

[**Demo plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FqM7qvmTMJ6LkgckkEAa?p=preview)

> The way you are doing is not a standard way of doing DOM manipulation
>   in AngularJS. The standard approach would be keep `ng-bind-html` attribute there itself in html rather than adding it dynamically.

### **Standard way**

**HTML**

```
<h1>Cleaner way</h1>
<pre ng-bind-html="binds"></pre>
```

**Code**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {
      $scope.binds="<h1>run</h1>";

    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o5hDpELkGbHr2cKhdGl6?p=preview)

Comment: you are right pankaj this not standard way of doing this but couldn't find another way of doing this. when i wrote the line you add i am getting error `$compile is not defined`

Comment: @AyyanAlvi you should include `$compile ` in your controller function

Comment: `app.controller('personCtrl',  function($scope,$http,$sce) {
    $compile(document.getElementsByClassName("lab")[0])(scope); });`

Comment: that's how should i do this?

Comment: @AyyanAlvi look at the demo plunkr which will give you a better idea of how to include dependency in controller function, basically you need to add one more parameter beside your `$scope` parameter of controller function separated them with `,`

Comment: @AyyanAlvi it should `app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope,$http,$sce, $compile) { $compile(document.getElementsByClassName("lab")[0])(scope); });`

Comment: @AyyanAlvi it should be `$scope`, I think you didn't look at the updated answer..

Comment: errors gone and `html-bind-html` is added but still not working :'(

Comment: @AyyanAlvi check my plunkr attached in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100835/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-ayyan-alvi).

Comment: I have never got answer in so much detail thanks my brother you are savior :)

Comment: @AyyanAlvi Glad to help you..Thanks :)